# Random variable and expectation

Tags: probability

This is a part of an exercise that I'm doing, in Durrett's Probability book.

> Let $X$ be a r.v which is not constant.  Let $\phi(\theta)=E\exp(\theta X)<\infty$ for $\theta\in(-\delta,\delta),$ and let $\psi(\theta)=\log \phi(\theta).$ Prove that $\psi$ is strictly convex.

I wanted to write $\psi$'' but it's not always well defined, because $\phi'$ is not always well defined. To calculate $\phi'$, we derive inside the expectation, so $\phi'(\theta)=E(X\exp(\theta X))$, but nothing garantees that $E(X\exp(\theta X))$ is finite.

I also tried to write the classic definition of convex functions $\psi(\lambda \theta_1+(1-\lambda)\theta_2)<\lambda\psi(\theta_1)+(1-\lambda)\psi(\theta_2),$ but it doesn't work either.

I hope that someone can help me solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Durrett also assumes that $X$ is not constant. You should be careful to put in *all* the conditions of the exercise.

Comment: You might want to expand on the reason why $\psi''$ could be *not always well defined*.

Comment: Yes I've forgotten the condition that says $X$ is not constant. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: *I hope that someone can help me solve it*. They do, but for that, you could explain what prevents, in some cases, $\psi''$ to be well defined.

Comment: did, I have now written in my question the reason why $\psi''$ could not be always well defined.

Comment: @Sasha It's corrected now. It was an error of typing.

Comment: And this reason is wrong: if $E(\exp(\theta X))$ is finite for every $|\theta|\lt\delta$, then $E(X\exp(\theta X))$ exists for every $|\theta|\lt\delta$. And, for that matter, for every nonnegative $n$, $E(|X|^n\exp(\theta X))$ is finite for every $|\theta|\lt\delta$.

Comment: Yes you're right, I've figured this out by Holder's inequality. Now the problem can be easily solved by calculating $\psi''$!

Comment: Indeed. (There are other, simpler, ways than Hölder but this is not terribly important.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that statement is actually true...

Take the simplest case, where X is a constant 0.  Then $\phi(\theta)$ is $1$ for all $\theta$, so $\psi(\theta)$ is a constant $0$, which is not strictly convex.  Check if the exercise adds other conditions you forgot.

Comment: I have added the condition $X$ is not constant. Sorry for that.